# Take one input for two list values

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, list

so i'm new to python and wanted to create noughts and crosses in a word format in python, so far i have this:

```
   move1 = int(input("Make your x move"))
   move2 = int(input ("make your y move"))
   boxes = [[0, 0, 0], 
           [0, 0, 0], 
           [0, 0, 0]]
```

I was just wondering if there is a way i wouldn't have to separate it out as `move1` and `move2` and just use `move` to do the same thing

many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can let the user input both moves in one line separating the integers with a space. Thus if one would move 1 in the x direction and 2 i the y direction, the inputs should be "1 2".
Then you would need to split this string into the two substrings "1" and "2" and then convert these two strings I to ints. Python strings have a 'split' method which you can use to split strings. You can probably find many examples of its usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tuple for that:

```py
moves = (int(input("Enter X:")), int(input("Enter Y:")))
```

Then you can access the x and y values from `moves[0]` or `moves[1]`